# Getting Segfault Error and Icinga2 fails with error 139

Tags: icinga2

Icinga2 version - 2.11.3-1

`May 24 09:31:21 master-icinga-1a kernel: icinga2[531]: segfault at 48 ip 000000000062a617 sp 00007fbd824b2990 error 4 in icinga2[400000+a0c000]`

We are stuck with this error for almost a week now. Don't see any errors when restarting Icinga2. Only when we check the status of Icinga2 and other logs we see this.

Whenever we check the status of Icinga2 it shows as failed. `(code=exited, status=139)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran `icinga2 daemon -x debug` and noticed that Icinga2 is loading states from file `/var/lib/icinga2/icinga2.state`.

This file was last updated a week ago, so emptied this file and restarted Icinga2. It worked.